# Best practice to retrieve a Firebase uids based on Facebook Ids

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is there an API or a workaround to translate a set of Facebook ids to Firebase Auth uids?

1. The signed in user's friends are retrieved into a list of Facebook ids via the Facebook SDK.
2. I am storing additional data for each of the users in a separate Firestore collection. The documents in the collection need to list the users' Facebook friends **by Firebase uids**.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in API to convert a Facebook user ID to a corresponding Firebase Authentication UID.

What you *can* do is create a map of the UID/Facebook IDs for each user of your app that signed into Firebase Authentication with Facebook. E.g.

```
facebookUsers
  facebookId1: firebaseUid1
  facebookId2: firebaseUid2
  .
  .
  .
```

With this in place you can find the Firebase UID for each Facebook user with a simple look up (if they're users of your Firebase app of course).
See these related questions too:

- [What value does Firebase Auth Identifier store from Facebook Login If user is not registered with email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859149/what-value-does-firebase-auth-identifier-store-from-facebook-login-if-user-is-no?rq=1)
- [Mapping Facebook friend id to Firebase uid in realtime database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906593/mapping-facebook-friend-id-to-firebase-uid-in-realtime-database)
- [How to store the uid of the Facebook users in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194209/how-to-store-the-uid-of-the-facebook-users-in-firebase)
- [How to determine if a Firebase user is signed in using facebook authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619628/how-to-determine-if-a-firebase-user-is-signed-in-using-facebook-authentication)

Comment: I see a problem with this solution.

The document size limit is 1 MB so if every entry in that list takes 100 bytes, the solution will break after 10.000 users.

I have the same issue myself, and I'm considering having a field in the user profile, containing the Facebook user. However, if I get list of friends IDs from the FB Graph API, and I want to look up the Firebase UIDs of all these users, it's not that easy if the Facebook UID is stored in each user profile.

Any suggestions that enables easy mass lookup/conversion without hitting the 1 MB document limit?

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote this answer, but I don't think I implied that you should store this map in a single document. You can *either* store it in a document *or* in a separate collection. The former requires fewer reads but has a scalability limit as you point out, while the latter doesn't have a scalability limit but requires more reads. Everyone will have to pick what works best for their use-case.